# Why does calculating Berry phase with stokes theorem give you a different result from a direct integration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, berry-pancharatnam-phase

For generic two level system $H = d(R) \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}$.

$$C_{-} =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{S^2} d\theta d\varphi \Omega_{\pm,\theta\varphi}=+1$$

$$
\gamma _{n}=\int _{\mathcal {S}}d\mathbf {S} \cdot \mathbf {\Omega } _{n}(\mathbf {R} ).
$$

However ccording to Stokes’ theorem, the integral of the Berry curvature over the parameter space can also be evaluated as the line integral of the Berry vector potential over the boundary of the parameter space.

However, since sphere has no boundary, we should expect the integral to be zero. This is not consistent with $C_{-}=1$.

Comment: Hello Sirui, welcome to the community. It's best to phrase the title of your post as a question.  I've made a suggestion

Answer (score 4):

This is the entire point of characteristic classes. Defining the Berry connection requires a choice of eigenstate for each one of the parameters. there is no global choice, so you cannot use Stokes.

For more detail see: https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys509/sp2017/bmaster.pdf

page 85 and 125 for Stokes and the fact that the area form is not exact, and page 264 for the no global section of the monopole bundle i.e your for  specific example $H={\bf d}\cdot \sigma$.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Why we can't globally chose eigenstate here?

Comment: @SiruiLu: Sorry I was too terse. I'll edit answer  to give links to detailed info.